# Parent and child pom layout with maven shade plugin

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, maven-shade-plugin

I'm trying to make a fat uber jar that contains all the projects.
If I do "mvn package", I get an uber jar under "blah" project taget folder. (blah project has the main class.)
The uber jar contains all the projects (as folders not jars), but when I run it, it doesn't seem to recognize feature1 & feature2 projects.

### parent pom:

```
<plugins>

  <!-- download source code in Eclipse, best practice -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
      <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
      <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <!-- Set a compiler level -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>com.a.blah.main</mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

</plugins>
<modules>
  <module>blahtask</module>
  <module>feature1</module>
  <module>feature2</module>
  <module>blahmessaging</module>
  <module>blah</module>
</modules>
```

### pom for blah

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.39</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.a.blah</groupId>
  <artifactId>blahtask</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.a.blah</groupId>
  <artifactId>blahmessaging</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.a.fs</groupId>
  <artifactId>feature1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.a.fs</groupId>
  <artifactId>feature2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I added dependencies for feature1 & feature2 above so that they are in the uber jar file. Is this wrong?
p.s. blahmessaging, feature1, & feature2 use classes/functions from blahtask.

It's really hard to find maven-shade-plugin examples with multiple projects. Hard to find how their poms files should be and how parent-child should be structured.

Comment: If anyone has made a jar that contains multiple projects and works well, please provide the examples. Thanks...

Comment: For example: https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee

Comment: BTW: Remove maven-eclipse-plugin cause it's retired a long time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be service loader issue...
I manually added class names that I'm using for serviceloader in feature1 & feature2 projects.

If you are using serviceloader, here is what I did.

feature1/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/"some super class"
feature2/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/"some super class"

if you open those two with a text editor, there is a sub class name for each that you need for serviceloader. I copied them and appended into the "some super class" file in the jar.